# Bluetooth listener

Tags: c#, bluetooth, 32feet

I'm using  InTheHand.Net.Personal (32feet.NET) library for c#, I make a direct conection (without Seriar COM port) and I can send comand to device:

```
String address = "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"; 
Guid mUUID = new Guid("00001101-0000-0000-0000-000000000000");

BluetoothAddress addr = BluetoothAddress.Parse(address);
var btEndpoint = new BluetoothEndPoint(addr, mUUID);
var btClient = new BluetoothClient();
btClient.Connect(btEndpoint);

Stream peerStream = btClient.GetStream();

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(peerStream);
sw.WriteLine("Hello World");
sw.Flush();
sw.Close();

btClient.Close();
btClient.Dispose();
btEndpoint = null;
```

However, I need catch asynchronously reply from device. But, I don't know what method for InTheHand.Net.Personal library use. Is anyway to attach any Listener or similar?